# How can I create an MDI application from a DLL (c++/mfc)

Tags: c++, mfc

I hope this isn't too confusing but I have the following situation:

- SDI Application that dynamically loads DLLs.
- These DLLs perform various tasks, spawn dialogs, etc.

Normally these dialogs that the DLLs create are fairly simple.  However I have many controls and need the features of an MDI application.  I can't separate this window into a new project, so I'm looking for a way to create it within the DLL and then initialize it as if it were a simple dialog.  I'm not particularly sure if this is possible but if so can someone point me in the correct direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check this codeproject article. It provides a helper class allowing to run an MDI Frame window as a popup. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4248/Modal-MFC-frame-window

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for thank you!

If you put this as an answer I will mark it correct.  My previous googling attempts didn't yield that.